# How to check if a subtring exists in a SELECT

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the query I am running below.  If a value from CMS does not have the fully qualified domain name with a . in it my query fails.  How can I check if my SUBSTRING is true before continuing?

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT SUBSTRING(s.server_name, 1, CHARINDEX('.', s.server_name)-1) AS [ServerName]
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_server_groups_internal g 
INNER JOIN 
    msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_registered_servers_internal s
        ON g.server_group_id = s.server_group_id
ORDER BY 
    ServerName
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `where` clause to check if server_name contains atleast 1 `.`

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(s.server_name, 1, CHARINDEX('.', s.server_name)-1) AS [ServerName]
FROM  msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_server_groups_internal g 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_registered_servers_internal s
ON g.server_group_id = s.server_group_id
where  CHARINDEX('.', s.server_name) > 0
ORDER BY ServerName
```